# Codecademy-Introduction to 'While' loops in JS

Tags: javascript, loops, while-loop

**Instructions**:

Write a while loop that logs "I'm looping!" to the console three times. You can do this however you like, but NOT with three console.log calls. Check the Hint if you need help!

```
var loop = function(){

while(){

//Your code goes here!

}

};

loop();
```

**The hint says:**

We actually know we need to loop three times, so we could use a for loop, but we'll use while this time.

If we create a variable called count and set it to 0 outside the loop (on line 2), then do count++ each time we console.log() inside the loop, we'll be able to track how many loops we've made. If we set the while condition to be count < 3, that should do the trick!

**I wrote:**

```
 var count = 0;

var loop = function(){

    while(count < 3){   

       var count = 3; 

    }

};

loop();
```

and it accepted it, but I didn't even add "I'm looping!" so I'm not sure why.

Comment: It should not have accepted that code. Think that's a bug in the testcases they do.

Comment: I actually figured it out. Do I take down the question?

Comment: Either delete the question or answer it yourself and accept your answer.